# Invoke-WebRequest to work with optional proxy

Tags: powershell

Duplicating Invoke-WebRequest to cover Proxy vs No Proxy situations

I have a script that needs to work with and without a proxy. Currently, everywhere I call Invoke-WebRequest I have to have two lines of code. One line to call if a Proxy is specified and one to call if a proxy is not specified. I would like to be able to use one call everywhere and just tack on the proxy stuff to the call if a proxy was specified.

```
    if ($Proxy) {
      Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $url -OutFile $tv_download -Proxy $Proxy -ProxyUseDefaultCredentials 
    }
    else {
        Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $url -OutFile $tv_download
    }
```

Edit, I did find one way to do this but if you have a different way please let me know. First, define $proxyInfo once at the beginning of the script.

```
    if($Proxy) {$proxyInfo = @{ Proxy = $Proxy; ProxyUseDefaultCredentials = $true} } else {$proxyInfo = @{}}
```

Then subsequently call Invoke-WebRequest throughout the script with this single line:

```
    Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $url -OutFile $tv_download @proxyInfo
```